# Find a node in an XML file - performance improvement in C#

Tags: c#, xml, performance

Say I need to find a particular node in an XML file, using C#.

```
<node attribute="my-target-attribute">
```

"my-target-attribute" is a variable input at runtime.

The node is in no particular place in the XML file, I basically just need to scan the entire XML hierarchy until I find a node with the matching attribute.

**Is there any way I can pre-process the XML so finding the node will be faster?** I need to keep the original XML structure in place. The XML file could potentially have 10,000 nodes.

Comment: There are two broadly different scenarios here: one is that you load XML into memory once, and then repeatedly do lookups on the in-memory representation (`XmlDocument`, `XPathDocument`, `XDocument` etc). The other is that you have to load the document from the file every time you need to do a lookup. Which one is yours?

Comment: I am open to either implementation. Another choice might be to pre-processes the file and load its contents into a database.

Comment: Do you need to get the XML node specifically (e.g. because you'll be handing it over to some other XML-processing API, like `XslCompiledTransform`) or just some data stored within it? If the latter, what kind of data (just a string, a bunch of random values, a tree of nodes...)?

Comment: Here are the steps: 1) Locate node matching target attribute. 2) Recursively walk up node's parents, building a string based on each traversed node's value. 3) Stop when root is reached.... steps two and three are no problem, it's just finding the initial node that is time-consuming.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can certainly preprocess the XML to make lookups faster:

```
Dictionary<string, XmlElement> elementMap = new Dictionary<string, XmlElement>();
AddElementToMap(doc.DocumentElement, elementMap);
...
private void AddElementToMap(XmlElement elm, Dictionary<string, XmlElement> elementMap)
{
   elementMap[elm.GetAttribute("attribute")] = elm;
   foreach (XmlElement child in elm.SelectNodes("node"))
   {
      AddElementToMap(child, elementMap);
   }
}
```

Once you've done this, a lookup is simple:

```
XmlElement elm = elementMap[value];
```

That code assumes that every element in your document is named "node", that every one has an attribute named "attribute", and that all of the attribute values are unique.  The code's more complicated if any of those conditions are untrue, but not exceptionally so.

Answer (score 1):

You could use xslt to transform the xml so that the node is in a known depth. Then when you select with XPath, you can select accordingly without using the // operator.

Comment: One reason why this may not work for me... my nodes are all named <node>.
So my XPATH would all be:
/node/node/node/node/[@attribute='my-target-attribute']

Comment: thats a pretty much freaky xml structure

Answer (score 1):

With VTD-XML (http://vtd-xml.sf.net) you can index the XML document into VTD+XML, 
which eliminate the overhead of parsing

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/XML/VTD-XML-indexing.aspx

Answer (score 0):

similar to another answer, you can use xpath similar like `selectNodes("//[@attribute='my-target-attribute']")`. `//` will search nodes in all level depths.